# Is it planned to have the NASA astronauts from the Artemis 2 mission fly again to the moon?

Tags: nasa, astronauts, future-missions, artemis-program

Just recently, NASA announced the astronauts  [who](https://spacenews.com/nasa-announces-crew-for-artemis-2-mission/) will fly to the moon (Which is pretty AMESOME!).

Is it planned to fly them on another Artemis mission or are the Artemis astronauts only flying once to the moon? From what I know, most of the Apollo astronauts only flew once to the moon. Except Jim Lovell, John Young, Eugene Cernan, David Scott and Thomas P. Stafford.

Since 5 astronauts from Apollo flew back and with Artemis NASA wants to establish a moon base, has NASA said anything about Artemis astronauts flying a second time to the moon?

Comment: You forgot to mention David Scott and Tom Stafford. Alan Bean also Skylab 3, Pete Conrad Skylab 2 and Tom Stafford Apollo Sojus. 5 Apollo Astronauts flew two missions, not 3.

Comment: @Uwe I fixed it